# What about instagram app revision?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I sent an Android application to be reviewed by instagram more than 2 months ago and I still have no response from them, the app is in pending review status. I have also tried to contact by email with no luck. Have they stopped reviewing application?

Comment: Facebook (who owns Instagram) has a **massive** review backlog because of their recent changes due to Cambridge Analytica.

Comment: I've seen this post (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/) about how to integrate Instagram. I did it by registering my client in instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/. Is this option deprecated and new apps have to be created using developer.facebook.com?

Comment: You're in the right place to create/manage an app, but I suspect the review teams are shared, and thus overloaded across both platforms.